# asp.net custom login page session alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, authentication

My website has custom made authentication system which uses sessions in asp.net instead of forms authentication.The sign in page gets the email and password, look it up in the database and set session true if it exists.The problem as you can guess is the session doesn't last more than 20 minutes by default.My question is how do i use cookies or any alternative solution to provide a way for users to be logged in until they do log out.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the page reload itself using javascript every 15 min of inactivity. The request would then prevent the timeout.

Comment: but that means i have to keep session in server's ram which is a scarce resource,is this the way the large sites implement?

Comment: That's because you're using InProc session. You should use SQL server session state; that way, what stays in RAM is just a small reference and that'll scale. If you're bumping against RAM problems, you need more than one server and a load balancer; a lot of work. Instead, check out azure; pretty cool stuff!

Comment: i mean the ram is not the problem,but i want the site to be scalable.How do i allow my users to stay logged in until they log out?i thought developers use cookies to do that.

Comment: No, you use SQL server session state and a load balancer; that's how it's done. The other newer option is cloud computing. The cookie is the reference the browser sends and this reference is then matched to find the data in the SQL server session state. Frankly, you should consider using MS Forms authentification; your custom made solution is probably more error prone and less scalable than what 500 engineers with unlimited budgets figured out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "patrick";
Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
```

Comment: I'm not using forms authentication in my site.I made it with sessions myself

Comment: try this, set the expire to like 10mins. Then have the page reload that cookie on postbacks, essentially resetting it. When it doesn't get posted back for over 10mins, it'll delete itself

Comment: also, if you store your login isAuthenticated value into a Session["isAuthenticated"] instead of plugging the cookie directly, your slidingTimeout should still apply.